# How can I make an AND and OR query using find options with TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I want to make a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM studies WHERE idUser = '12489184291' AND (type LIKE '%something%' OR type LIKE '%something%')
```

Is this viable? This is because I'd like to use a LIKE operator to search by not exact values  within a range of defined values. For example, within all studies from User A, search by the ones that start with a name or type like "study for"...

Right now I have this:

```js
    const searchQuery = getSearchQuery(search, on);
    const filterQuery = getFilterQueries(filters);

        req.options = {
            where: [
                ...searchQuery,
                ...filterQuery,
            ]
        }
        
const getSearchQuery = (search: string, on: string) => {
    if (!search) return [];

    const searchQuery = `%${search}%`;

    switch (on) {
        case 'estudios':
            return [
                {
                    nombre: ILike(searchQuery)
                },
                {
                    tipoModificacion: ILike(searchQuery)
                },
                {
                    antecedentes: ILike(searchQuery)
                },
                {
                    observaciones: ILike(searchQuery)
                },
            ]
        default: return [];
    }
}

const getFilterQueries = (filters: {}) => {
    let filterObj: any = {};

    const urlFilters = new URLSearchParams(filters);

    urlFilters.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (key === 'createdAt' || key === 'responseDate') {
            filterObj = {
                ...filterObj,
                ...dateRange(key, value)
            }
            return;
        } else {
            filterObj[key] = value;
        }
    });

    if (Object.keys(filterObj).length > 0) {
        return [filterObj]
    } else {
        return [];
    }
};
```

And this is working like a general OR due to my where: [...values], is there a way to have an AND and an OR within the same where using findOptions? Or will it be recommendable to use a QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QueryBuilder:

```
await studyRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('study')
        .where({ idUser: 12489184291 })
        .andWhere(`(type ILIKE '${searchQuery}' OR type ILIKE '${searchQuery}')`)
```

P.S. Due to lack of information, such as entity and repository names you might need to edit provided code